# Change which elelemt that gets slided by mmenu jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I'm using the mmenu plugin for jQuery to create a slide in off canvas menu. My problem is that I have a markup that is not ideal and doesn't have a page wrapper. The result is that the slide out page gets placed on the wrong element, everything gets white, and I'm now trying to change it.

```
<body>
<nav id="menu" class="mm-menu mm-horizontal mm-offcanvas mm-right mm-front">
    <ul class="mm-list mm-panel mm-opened mm-current" id="mm-0">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="mm-subopen" href="#mm-1"></a><a href="/about">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- some more markup generated by the plugin -->
</nav>

<div class="mm-page mm-slideout" style="min-height: 949px;">
    <div id="DeltaPlaceHolderCustomizeSiteActionsAndQuickLaunch"></div>
    <div id="imgPrefetch" style="display:none">
        <img src="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=23">
        <img src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png">
        <img src="/_themes/691/spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng?ctag=693">
    </div>
</div>

// more markup
</body>
```

This is the markup that gets generated, which doesn't work at all, since the content of the page is not in that div that gets `mm-slideout` class.

I've tried setting the [pageNodeType](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/tutorial/setting-up-the-html.html) (as described there) to the form element that wraps the page at a lower level (few levels down from the `body` tag), like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var page = $('#aspnetForm');

        $("#menu").mmenu(
            {
                offCanvas: {
                    position: "right",
                    zposition: "front"
                }
            }, {
                offCanvas: {
                    pageNodeType: "form"
                }
            })
    });
```

And also tried [setting a specific element as the page](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/custom-events.html), (as described there), like this:

```
 $("#menu").mmenu().trigger("setPage.mm", [page]);
```

But nothing happens. I know that it is being read, since I can change the position of the menu to right.

When I do only the pageNoteType. all that happens is that the element with class mm-slideout gets another element inside it with the same classes. But nothing makes it change what gets slided.

I know that my configuration says that the page shouldn't be slided, but that the menu should slide over it, but as far as I can tell I still need to change what gets the mm-page and mm-slide classes. At the moment everything on the page just gets white when I open the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pageNodeType` should be `pageNodetype` (note the lower case t). The rest looks right, that should do it.